# Reevaluating CommandParameter on Button press

Tags: wpf

Heres a quick question. I have an XAML defined like this:

```
<ComboBox Height="25" Width="150" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Simulations}"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Simulation}"/>

<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
Content="{Binding Path=Simulations.CurrentItem.OptionsPanel}"/>

<Button Content="Simulate" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Margin="0,0,0,20"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75"
Command="{Binding Path=Simulations.CurrentItem.SimulateCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Simulations.CurrentItem.CommandParameter}"/>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when a user picks a simulation from the combobox, a panel is shown that has controls specific to the selected simulation. Each simulation has it's own unique set of parameters, and as a result, a unique "Simulate" command is required for each simulation. The XAML above works almost exactly as required. When a user selects a simulation, a specific user control is being inserted into a ScrollViewer, and a proper command is set for the button. The problem I have is with CommandParameter. It is evaluated immediately after simulation selection, but at that time most of the options are still null since the user didn't have a chance to modify them yet. So, basically, what I need is to force CommandParameter to be reevaluated on button press. Perhaps someone could help with that, or suggest a better implementation of the functionality I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you bind both the ItemsSource and SelectedItem of the ComboBox to Simulations? Shouldn't SelectedItem be bound to Simulations.CurrentItem ?

Comment: @failedprogramming typo, changed it to Simulation. In essence, I have a CollectionView that knows what item is selected, but this CollectionView exist only in ViewModel. The actual Model hidden behind VM doesn't know anything about CollectionView, "selection" or controls, but it needs to get that selected Simulation object somehow. I guess a more orthodox method would be to capture selection changed event in VM and set Model.Simulation from there, but I found out that exposing and binding to a model property (as in VM.Simulation == VM.Model.Simulation) as SelectedItem work just as good.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `CommandParameter` is a property on your `Simulation` class, you need to make sure your Simulation class either implements the CommandParameter property as a `DependencyProperty`, or the Simulation class itself should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` with change notifications being sent on its `CommandParameter` property.

If either of these approaches is implemented, then your CommandParameter property should update your button's command property whenever it is changed